# When creating new process using exec() in nodejs, does it run in parallel with current process, how nodejs handles it?

Tags: node.js, multiprocessing, exec, child-process

Since nodejs is single threaded language, how does it creates new processes and handles it.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;  
exec('my.bat', (err, stdout, stderr) => {  
  if (err) {  
    console.error(err);  
    return;  
  }  
  console.log(stdout);  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The child_process.spawn(), child_process.fork(), child_process.exec(), and child_process.execFile() methods all follow the idiomatic asynchronous programming pattern typical of other Node.js APIs.

Each of the methods returns a ChildProcess instance. These objects implement the Node.js EventEmitter API, allowing the parent process to register listener functions that are called when certain events occur during the life cycle of the child process.

The child_process.exec() and child_process.execFile() methods additionally allow for an optional callback function to be specified that is invoked when the child process terminates.

Documentation [link](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).